Qubit entanglement in linear combination of unitaries Qiskit calculation
This is a follow-up to my previous question (Linear combination of unitaries with Qiskit circuit) where I ask how to construct a linear combination of unitaries (LCU) circuit in Qiskit.

For that two-qubit example, it requires adding a control qubit to do LCU.  Assuming I don't need the control qubit for any future calculations, I want to figure out the most efficient way to find the psi statevector:

If the psi qubits are entangled with ctrl qubits, psi is not a pure state and statevector simulation is not possible.  Instead one must find the density matrix of the whole system, take the trace over the ctrl register, then recover the psi statevector.

If psi and ctrl qubits are not entangled, we can recover the statevector using statevector simulation.


My question is, does LCU always produce an entangled (or unentangled) state?  If not, how can I tell whether LCU for some arbitrary matrix will entangle the psi and ctrl registers?

In the LCU algorithm, you don't just discard the ancillary qubit. For the algorithm to work correctly, you actually measure the ancillary qubit and recover $A|\psi\rangle$ (up to a normalization factor) only if the measurement outcome of the ancillary qubit is $0$. And once you perform this measurement, the state will be separable.
So, the code to implement the circuit will also need a measurement step:
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp, Operator


# Create non-unitary matrix
a = 0.25
b = 0.75

A = np.array([[a,  0, 0,  b],
              [0, -a, b,  0],
              [0,  b, a,  0],
              [b,  0, 0, -a]])


# Pauli Decomposition of A
LCU = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(A)
LCU_coeffs = LCU.coeffs
LCU_ops = LCU.paulis

L = len(LCU_coeffs)              # Total number of Paulis
M = int(2**np.ceil(np.log2(L)))  # Closest power of 2 to encode coefficients in statevector
pad = M - L                      # Value by which statevector needs to be padded


# lists of α coeffs and U unitaries for LCU
α_lst = np.pad(np.sqrt(LCU_coeffs)/np.linalg.norm(np.sqrt(LCU_coeffs)), pad_width=(0,pad))
U_lst = [op.to_instruction() for op in LCU_ops]


# Define ψ
ψ = np.array([1,0,0,0])


# Specify number of qubits
N = A.shape[0]         # Size of square-matrix A
n = int(np.log2(N))    # Number of qubits needed to encode A
m = int(np.log2(M))    # Number of qubits to control unitaries


# Create LCU registers
qr_ψ = QuantumRegister(n, name='ψ')
qr_c = QuantumRegister(m, name= 'ctrl')
cr_c = ClassicalRegister(m)


# Create LCU circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr_ψ, qr_c, cr_c)
qc.prepare_state(ψ, qr_ψ)
qc.prepare_state(α_lst,qr_c)

for i in range(L):
    ctrl = np.binary_repr(i,m)
    U_ctrl = U_lst[i].control(m,ctrl_state=ctrl)
    qc.append(U_ctrl,qr_c[:]+qr_ψ[:])

qc.prepare_state(α_lst,qr_c).inverse()
qc.measure(qr_c,cr_c)
qc.save_statevector()


And then, a simulation that gets executed until you measure a 0:
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.quantum_info import partial_trace

simulator = AerSimulator()
qc_t = transpile(qc, simulator)

n_out = 1000     # Number of iterations before timing out
done = False

while not done:
    result = simulator.run(qc_t,shots=1).result()
    meas_result = list(result.get_counts().keys())[0]
    meas_sv = result.get_statevector()

    n_out -= 1
    
    if int(meas_result) == 0 or n_out == 0:
        meas_sv = partial_trace(meas_sv,range(n,n+m)).to_statevector()
        done = True
        
print(meas_sv)

This should print the Statevector after applying the non-unitary matrix $A$ (up to a normalization factor).
Just one note, I added a "time out" variable to the while loop because, in the LCU, the probability of measuring a 0 in the ancillary qubits can be very small depending on the way you setup the problem (or even 0 if you don't set it up correctly).
Alternative to Qiskit Aer:
If you're having issues with Aer's Statevector simulator, you can:

Remove/comment these two lines of code in the circuit definition:

qc.measure(qr_c,cr_c)
qc.save_statevector()


Run the following code which uses the Statevector class from the quantum_info module:

from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector, partial_trace

sv = Statevector(qc)

n_out = 1000     # Number of iterations before timing out
done = False

while not done:
    meas_result, meas_sv = sv.measure(range(n,n+m))
    n_out -= 1
    print(meas_result == '0')
    
    if meas_result == '0' or n_out == 0:
        meas_sv = partial_trace(meas_sv,range(n,n+m)).to_statevector()
        display(meas_sv)
        done = True


Thanks for the detailed answer.  I was wondering which version of Qiskit and Qiskit Aer you are using?  I use v1.3.1 and v.0.14.2 respectively.  When I run your code in a Python notebook, I get kernel error Kernel Restarting: The kernel for mycode.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.  If I run it on IDLE shell, the kernel just restarts.

Yes, I have ran into this issue before too. Not sure what triggers it, but it seems to be a bug with Qiskit Aer. I edited the response above for an alternative way to simulate this without using Aer
